# No matching service worker detected - Angular 9

Tags: service-worker, angular9, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa, service-worker-config

this is my first time working with service workers and I am having difficulties because I always get this error in the Network - Application - Manifest tab:

[image]

**Some technical details:**

package.json

```
"@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/localize": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/pwa": "^0.901.12",
"@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/service-worker": "~9.1.0",
```

angular.json

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/appName/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/appName/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "projects/appName/src/ngsw-config.json"
```

manifest.webmanifest

```
{
  "name": "app name",
  "short_name": "app",
  "description": "test test",
  "theme_color": "#003f8b",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "16x16",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/flatwork.svg",
      "sizes": "150x150",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/icon-withdrawal-mark.png",
      "sizes": "27x23",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/incoming.svg",
      "sizes": "150x150",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/input.svg",
      "sizes": "150x150",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/master_data_icon.svg",
      "sizes": "150x150",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/outgoing.svg",
      "sizes": "150x150",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/output.svg",
      "sizes": "150x150",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/rental_outfit.svg",
      "sizes": "150x150",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/repair.svg",
      "sizes": "150x150",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/scanned_on.svg",
      "sizes": "150x150",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/tooltip_icon.svg",
      "sizes": "150x150",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    }
  ]
}
```

index.html

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#003f8b" />
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest" />

<body>
  <bar-root></bar-root>
  <noscript
    >Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript
  >
</body>
```

app.module

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('../ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: environment.production
    }),
    ... // other imports
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: SwRegistrationOptions,
      useFactory: () => ({
        enabled: environment.production,
        registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately',
      }),
    },
  ]
```

ngsw-config.json

```
{
  "$schema": "../../../node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, here is the project structure to check the path imports:

[image]

What am I missing? Also, what is the best way to test any config changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution regarding my issue, some small changes were required:

`app.module` - adjusted the service worker registration

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
  enabled: environment.production,
  // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the app is stable
  // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
  registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000',
}),
```

In `angular.json` if you have multiple builds for different environments, lets say production and qa, you can add these configs on both:

```
"serviceWorker": true,
"ngswConfigPath": "projects/appName/ngsw-config.json"
```

// or whichever path you have for the ngsw-config.json, but this will probably be generated automatically when installing @angular/pwa.

To test your changes, run `ng build` or ng `build --prod` or any other environments you want to test on.

To see the build for the prod environment I used [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server), which you can find in npm and install it. Your build will be created in a dist folder, and in the root folder of the app run(9191 being the port, you can change it to whatever you like, just make sure nothing runs on it):

```
http-server -p 9191 -c-1 dist/appName
```

You can open you 9191 localhost port and check in the Deveoper Tools, Application tab, under Manifest and Service Workers to make sure everything is running.

I also removed ngsw-worker.js from my project because it is moved automatically from node_modules when you do the builds.